# Log Rotating into a Directory using Python

Tags: python, logging, rotation

I have a file called Poller.log and it's appended by log details all the time. I want this log file to be rotated everyday and limited by 30 days. Thus, the code works well.

Now I want this logs that has been rotated to be in a folder (i.e. logs/poller.log.2011-03-04_15-36). Is there anyway to direct where this rotated file should be created?

This python script will be executed by Cron.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

LOG_FILENAME = '/home/stackoverflow/snmpdata/poller.log'

# Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
poll_logger = logging.getLogger('pollerLog')

# Add the log message handler to the logger
log_rotator = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME, when='d', interval=1, backupCount=30, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False)
poll_logger.addHandler(log_rotator)

# Roll over on application start
poll_logger.handlers[0].doRollover()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python logging handler don't allow to do that easily. You might have 2 way of achieve this :

1. The simplest way would to setup LOG_FILENAME to be already in logs/poller.log, and if you want to access to your poller.log anywhere else, use a symlink :)
2. Create your own handler starting from TimedRotatingFileHandler, and copy/paste the doRollover() from /usr/lib/python2.X/logging/handlers.py, TimedRotatingFileHandler class. And change :

```
dfn = self.baseFilename + "." + time.strftime(self.suffix, timeTuple)
```

to

```
dfn = os.path.join('logs', os.path.basename(self.baseFilename)) + "." + time.strftime(self.suffix, timeTuple)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll take the first solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the extra dependency you could always use the rollover logging module in twisted. Twisted has a logfile module that allows for daily logs, weekly logs, or even monthly logs like this situation.

Comment: I'm gonna need to look into Twisted.

Answer (score 0):

I added this bit of code for a separate process to move any log backups to a folder.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import shutil, os, glob
import zipfile
import schedule
import time
import threading

zip_file_name = "Log.zip"
zip_file_path = "Logs/LogsArchive/Log.zip"

source_directory = "Logs"
archive_directory = "Logs/LogsArchive"


def moveAllFilesinDir(srcDir, dstDir, allLogs = False):
    try:
    # Check if both the are directories
        if os.path.isdir(srcDir) and os.path.isdir(dstDir):
            # Iterate over all the files in source directory

            if allLogs == False:
                for filePath in glob.glob(srcDir + '/*.*.*'):
                    # Move each file to destination Directory
                    shutil.move(filePath, dstDir)
            elif allLogs == True:
                for filePath in glob.glob(srcDir + '/*.*'):
                    # Move each file to destination Directory
                    shutil.copy(filePath, dstDir)

        else:
            debug_logger.debug("LoggingModule: - moveAllFilesinDir - srcDir & dstDir should be Directories")
    except Exception as ex:
        error_logger.error("Error in LoggingModule - moveAllFilesinDir", exc_info=True)
```

Only log files with a 3 part extension will be moved over  "name.log.date"
I am working on a process to zip the archive folder now.

update:
Here's is the Zip process

```
def createZipDir(path):
    #delete old zipfile if exists, but leave old zipfile if no other files exist
    if len(os.listdir(path)) > 1:
        zipFile = zip_file_path
        if os.path.isfile(zipFile):
            os.remove(zipFile)
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if file != zip_file_name:
                    zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))
        zipf.close()
    else:
        debug_logger.debug("LoggingModule: - createZipDir - no files found, zip file left in place.")
```

Deleting the old files:

```
def deleteOldFilesinDir(srcDir):
    try:
    # Check if both the are directories
        if os.path.isdir(srcDir):
            # Iterate over all the files in source directory
            for filePath in glob.glob(srcDir + '/*.*'):
                if filePath != zip_file_path:
                    os.remove(filePath)
        else:
            print("srcDir & dstDir should be Directories")
    except Exception as ex:
        error_logger.error("Error in LoggingModule - deleteOldFilesinDir", exc_info=True)
```

Here's the whole process:

I have the runArchiveProcess set on a schedule to run once a week.

```
def runArchiveProcess(allFiles = False):
    debug_logger.debug("LoggingModule: Archive process started.")
    moveAllFilesinDir(source_directory, archive_directory, allFiles)
    createZipDir(archive_directory)
    deleteOldFilesinDir(archive_directory)
    debug_logger.debug("LoggingModule Archive process completed.")
```

And the scheduler bit:

```
#only kicked off in own thread...
def runScheduler():
    debug_logger.debug("LoggingModule - runScheduler - don't call this function outside of LoggingModule as it runs in own thread.")
    schedule.every().monday.at("00:00:00").do(runArchiveProcess)
    #schedule.every(10).seconds.do(runArchiveProcess).do(runArchiveProcess) #for testing

    try:
        while True:
            debug_logger.debug("LoggingModule checking scheduler...")
            #Checks whether a scheduled task is pending to run or not
            schedule.run_pending()
            debug_logger.debug("LoggingModule Scheduler sleeping...")
            time.sleep(60 * 60) # checks every 1 hour
            #time.sleep(10)  # for testing
    except Exception as ex:
        error_logger.error("Error in LoggingModule - runScheduler", exc_info=True)


def runSchedulerThread():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=runScheduler)
    thread.start()
```